# How to understand SM-17 alogrithm factor f(R,S)

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to understand and implement the SM-17 algorithm in a flashcard application and getting trouble to understand the function f(R,S).

I am not able to imagine what will be the steps to calculate f(R,S) using the spaced repetition concept.

Below is the details of my work:

Theoretical SInc() function is the root where the baseline mapping of maximum stability increase to difficulty is established:

```
SInc:=(5*(1-Difficulty)+1)*f(R,S)+1

where:

    SInc - stability increase
    Difficulty - difficulty in 0..1 range
    f(R,S) - component of SInc that depends on R and S
```

This baseline formula currently determines the cutoff value for hardest possible items at SInc that is N times less than the maximum value possible for easiest items (with N=(6*f(R,S)+1)/(f(R,S)+1)).

How can I implement the formula programmatically?

Comment: You ever figure this out?